# Definition of good reduction

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, curves

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $S$ be a Dedekind scheme of dim $1$,  $K$ be the fraction field,
and $C$ be a normal connected projective curve over $K$.

For closed point $p\in C$, is next two notion is different?

> (1)there is model $\cal{C}$ over $\operatorname{Spec} \cal{O}_{C,p}$ s.t. $\cal{C}$ is smooth over $\operatorname{Spec} \cal{O}_{C,p}$ .

> (2) there is model
> $\cal{C}$ over $\operatorname{Spec} \cal{O}_{C,p}$
> s.t. $\cal{C}\times \operatorname{Spec}k(p)$ is smooth over $\operatorname{Spec} k(p)$ .

where $k(p)$ is residue field of $p$. It's trivial that (1)$\Rightarrow $ (2) by base change. When we say $C$ is good reduction at $p$, which does it  imply?

I have second question. When we say $C$ has good reduction, which means of the following?

> (a)for all $p\in C$, $C$ has good reduction at $p$.

> (b) there is smooth model over $S$.

Comment: You should be a little bit more precise with what you mean by "model". Presumably, a model is meant to be a flat projective scheme $X$ over $S$ whose generic fibre  $X_K$ is isomorphic to $C$. In this case, $(2)$ also implies $(1)$ because a flat projective morphism with smooth fibres is smooth. Liu's book on arithmetic curves and algebraic geometry is a great reference for all this.

Comment: Also, (a) and (b) are equivalent. To have good reduction at all points $p$ (in the sense of $(a)$) is the same as having a global smooth proper model. But proving this requires some work. (Of course, (b) implies (a). To prove that (a) implies (b) you have to glue models. )